# how to read interleaved data with memmapfile()?

Tags: matlab, file-io, binaryfiles, bigdata, memory-mapped-files

I have a large (4GB+) data file I'd like to access. It contains samples *i* of a number of different signals {**a**, **b**, **c**} as follows:

```
a_1 b_1 c_1 a_2 b_2 c_2 .... a_n b_n c_n
```

I would like to use [memmapfile](http://www.automatedtrader.net/blogs/mathworks/143832/using-memmapfile-to-navigate-through-big-data-binary-files) to retrieve, say, the **a** stream. Since I know the number of signals and the number of samples, I tried:

```
m = memmapfile('data.dat','Format',{'int16',[nSignals 1],'sid'},'repeat',nSamples);
```

but this returns the useless *m* field

```
Data: nSamples x 1 struct array with fields:
          sid
```

Of course the following works fine, but is very slow:

```
m = memmapfile('data.dat','Format','int16');
a = m.Data(1:nSignals:end);
```

How can I recover **a** without having to access the full data matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using FREAD and specifying the appropriate `skip` value. The following will read the signal `a` in one go:

```
% 3 interleaved signals each of type int16
nSignals = 3;

% amount of bytes to skip after reading each sample
szINT16 = 2;                   % sizeof(int16)=2
skipBytes = (nSignals-1)*szINT16;

% number of samples in each signal (Inf to read all samples)
nSamples = Inf;

fid = fopen('data.dat','rb');
a = fread(fid, nSamples, '*int16', skipBytes);
fclose(fid);
```

You could do the same for the other two signals, you just have to seek the right start location:

```
fseek(fid, szINT16*1, 'bof');
b = fread(fid, nSamples, '*int16', skipBytes);

fseek(fid, szINT16*2, 'bof');
c = fread(fid, nSamples, '*int16', skipBytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something as:

```
m = memmapfile('data.dat', 
               'Format', 
               { 'int16'  [1 1] 'a'; 'int16' [1 1] 'b'; 'int16' [1 1] 'c'}, 
               'Repeat', nSamples);

a = m.Data(:).a; % extract all instances of a
```